# What is your idea about this advertising note

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I need to advertise a medicine. I am going to write a sentence to advertise it. I have written the sentence in my question in the following way. What do you think? Did I wrote it properly or I have to change it's construction or phrase:

> **(The name of the medicine)**
>
> ***The / a*** reliable choice for prostate cancer

Which article is required here?

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'a' it'll look like there are many reliable ways and this is one of them, whereas if you use 'the' it seems that your medicine is the only reliable (At least it looks so to me). Now that's up to you to choose which one.

Comment: I knew that well @mok. I was looking for the commonest way to indicate such a concept like a native. As I mentioned, it was an advertising note... ;)

Comment: Ok, though it's an advertisement, honesty is the best choice :)

Comment: Safest would be to use "a", since no doubt there are other medications available.

Comment: @user3169> I think so.